# simple AWS Batch array job stuck in pending

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-processing

I'm following the print-color AWS batch tutorial for an array batch job from the official amazon batch user guide on page 23 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch_user.pdf . It is supposed to be a very simple tutorial, but I find that my submitted array job is stuck in pending for an indefinite period of time.

Does anybody have an idea? I can't find more info to know if there is a bug. And there is nothing in cloud watch.[image link Pending job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gPXW.png)

Thanks in advance.